# Generating Reminders or Alarms in a Worklight mobile application

Tags: notifications, ibm-mobilefirst, alarm, reminders

I am creating a medical app where in i am storing the medicine schedule and appointments with doctors and similar things.. I want my worklight app to generate alarms or reminders using this data.

I dont know how to proceed. I guess i would have to add calender entries as and when new entries are added in the above mentioned features.

How should i go about doing this in worklight and make it work across all the mobile platforms..

I am using Worklight v6.1 and storing the details in DB2 database.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go cross-platform in a mobile web app, you can use a 3rd party library such as jQuery Mobile, Dojo, Sencha and others; these will provide the tools to create a consistent UI experience across the various platforms as well as the ability to tweak each with its specific nuances. Or, you can just write it from scratch, custom. We are, after all, talking here about HTML, CSS and JS...

Specifically in Worklight, there are training materials that cover how to integrate such libraries in your project, and much more.

- You *must* review the [IBM Worklight Getting Started training material](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/library/) before starting **any** project.
- Not doing so will only cause you frustration and you will build yourself a bad foundation to work with as you progress with the development.

Regarding to the application logic...
In general you could do something like the following. Consult with your Product Manager about the actual app requirements.

1. You can create some database table with appointment dates, appointment types, doctor names, etc
2. You can implement some logic and UI to add new entries to this table

   - you collect the data and invoke an SQL adapter procedure to add the data
   - [Worklight provides training modules for explaining how to use adapters](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/library/)
3. You can implement some logic in the client-side to send once a day an adapter request to the database and retrieve all appointments based on appointment date/type or doctor name, etc
4. You can display an alert in case such appointments are found... or display it in the UI, send a local push notification
5. You could also implement a servlet that will do similar database queries and if such appointments were found, then send a push notification to the application

The above is a high-level, very general, idea of what can be done.  I don't think we're here to implement this for you.  Start writing some code; if you encounter problems, ask Technical questions, provide your implementation, etc...

Comment: Thanks for the info.. So i can do local push notification from the app itself ?

Comment: I'm sure that would be possible by creating a Cordova plug-in that taps into this Native ability, at least in iOS.

Comment: @DevrathND, search for "[worklight] location notifications". You will find answers for this. if my answer helped resolve your problem, please mark as answered.